# MacBook Air OS Big Sur will not update

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, big-sur

No matter how many times I try to update to the latest MacOS Big Sur release, my MacBook Air will not update. It is currently stuck at the version it arrived with last fall: Version 11.1. After the New Your Times article about the security issue of Apple products, I am anxious to fix this so I can download any fixes. I am horrible at technology; any ideas for a computer-challenged person like me? Thank you!

Comment: Which steps are you taking and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Click Apple icon () in the top-right corner. In the menu, click on **System Preference** to open it. In ``System Preferences`` click on  *Software Update*. In `Software Update`, click on the **Update Now** or **Upgrade Now** button. This will download all the macOS Big Sur updates and install it on your system automatically. Make sure you are connected to the internet, and your MacBook is plugged for charging. This may take anywhere between an hour to a few hours, depending on your net connection speed. **If you are getting any error here, or facing any issue with these steps, tell us.**

Comment: There are no error messages; it just never downloads completely and/or never installs. I've been trying for months to update my Big Sur 11.1 to latest versions--never with any success. Now I feel an urgent need to get the security issues fixed. Am exhausted by this problem.

Comment: Could you get to an Apple Store? They'd certainly be able to figure this out.

Comment: If you are using wifi, you may be experiencing interference which is slowing your connection and choking on the update or making it seem to take forever. How long are you waiting for the download? Are you doing anything that might interrupt the download?

Comment: If you can use the Terminal, try `softwareupdate -d -a`.

Answer (score 1):

If your "Upgrade Now" button does not work, try restarting your MacBook and try again. If it still doesn't work try pressing "Automatically keep my Mac up to date".